# A graph is determined up to homeomorphism by its edges and vertices?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Section $\S$64 of Munkres' Topology talks about (finite) linear graphs. A Hausdorff space $G$ is a (finite) linear graph if it can be written as the union of finitely many arcs, each of wich intersect in at most a common end point (an arc is just a space homeomorphic to a compact interval of the real line).

Just after that, the book mentions a graph is determined, up to homeomorphism, by listing its vertices and specifying wich pairs of vertices have an edge joining them.

Although the comment seems rather intuitive, I am not convinced. Can someone provide a sketch of a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition you have is correct, and it should already amount to the following sketch of a proof. The idea is: Given such $G$ and such a list, we construct a new space $X$ by using *only* the list, and show that $G$ and $X$ are homeomorphic.

So the list starts with a finite set $V$ of vertices,
followed by a set $E$ of unordered pairs ${v,w}\subset V$. (Note that we cannot have $v=w$ because the corresponding arc in $G$ would then actually be a loop). Let $n=|V|$ and enumerate the elements of  $V$ as $1,2,\ldots, n$.
For every $1\le i<j\le n$, let $I_{\{i,j\}}=(i,j)\times [0,1]$.
So far we have edge-many disjoint copies of the standard interval.
Now identify the relation  $(i,j,t)\sim(k,l,u)$ as

- $i=k$ and $t=u=0$ or
- $j=l$ and $t=u=1$ or
- $i=l$ and $t=0$ and $u=1$ or
- $j=k$ and $t=1$ and $u=0$ or
- $(i,j,t)=(k,l,u)$

This is an equivalenced relation ans allows us to define $X$ as a quotient space of our collection of edges. The construction of the homeomorphism $X\to G$ is quite straightforward as we have by definition a homeomorphism $f\colon [0,1]\to A$ for every arc $A$ constituting $G$, and we pick either $f$ or its reverse, $t\mapsto f(1-t)$, in order to match the correct interval end points with the correct vertex. I leave the technicalities of showing that this actually gives a homeomorphism to you (you will need the Hausdorff property at some point)

Comment: That's a great answer! Just what I was looking for. Thanks!